# Facebook native share dialog sent from iOS and not FbAppName?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, social-networking, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm implementing Facebook SDK 3.1 in an iOS application.
And I've got it all to work, except, for one tiny issue.

When I'm using the code below to share native through the SDK, what actually gets posted is said to be posted from iOS and not my facebook application.

```
[FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:viewController
                                       session:FBSession.activeSession
                                   initialText:postText
                                        images:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:postImage, nil]
                                          urls:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:postURL, nil]
                                       handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
                                           [self handleShareResult:result error:error];
                                           
                                       }];
```

Here is an example picture:

[image: Facebook post text: Like, Comment, Share, 9 minutes ago via iOS]

I would like it to say via "Facebook app name" instead of iOS.

Comment: did u got the answer.. PLease help me  @Joakim Engstrom

Comment: Have not gotten the answer yet, this is not a big priority for me, but if I fix it I will post the fix here.

Answer (score 1):

Currently with the iOS6 native share dialog you'll get the "via iOS" attribution.

Comment: I have not tried this but should not this work on native accounts? http://damir.me/posts/facebook-authentication-in-ios-6
To do excatly as I wish, what I want to do is to do it in the facebook SDK